# IOS Developing:Tab Bar Item's Image Display a Blue Square

Tags: ios, swift

The bar item images I prepared are about 35*35 
and I use the **Sketch** to export the [1x & 2x] size images;
(I can't insert any images for instances at here because of my zero reputation//Sorry about this!)

Then it displays a blue square :<

the function and title of **Item** is OK

BUT just the icons are wrong

Could someone tells me how to fix it!
Appreciate!!!

Comment: Can you provide more details as to what you have tried so far ?

Comment: How do you add the images to the tabbar?

Comment: @QuantumLicht  I can't upload any images otherwise I can show u the whole picture

Comment: @piyuj import (1x 2x 3x)images to media library, and set tabbar's icon in attribute inspector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure it out!

**There is nothing wrong with your code or setting**

It's about your **IMAGEs**

You can just look at the apps on your phone.(almost)Any tab bar item icons are in gray.

So the Icon will just display their **UN Hollow** parts in gray!!

[Additionally,according to official API,they wrote like this:

By default, unselected and selected images are automatically created from the **alpha values in the source images**. To prevent system coloring, provide images with ***UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal***.

]

Consequently the solution is : USE Sketch to make your instance's icon heart-part to be hollow

Comment: can you collaborate?

Comment: @eyal what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add @3x image too.